# Reading boolean values from file always return "True"

Tags: python, game-engine

```
from bge import logic
path = logic.expandPath("//")

def save():
    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner 
    # 'info' is what will be saved to the file.
    # Example:
    # info = str(*What you want to save*)

    info = str(own['pink'])+","+str(own['red'])

    file = open(path+str(own)+".txt", 'w')    
    file.write(str(info))


def load():
    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    file = open(path+str(own)+'.txt','r')
    line = file.readline().replace('\n','').split(',')
    own['pink'] = bool(line[0])
    own['red'] = bool(line[1])
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  because it is fundamentally about how python interprets the string representation of a Boolean. (not a bad question, just wrong place)

Answer (score 1):

instead of casting to a boolean you can use them in an expression:

```
file = open(path+str(own)+'.txt','r')
line = file.readline().split(',')
own['pink'] = line[0] == "True"
own['red']  = line[1] == "True"
```

Comment: I want to add that "bool(string)" will return False when the string is empty (or None), otherwise it returns True regardless of the content

Answer (score 1):

fundamentally this is a Python specific question / misunderstanding

```
some_string = "True, False, False, True, False"
items = some_string.split(', ')

print(items)
# ['True', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'False']

print([bool(i) for i in items])
# [True, True, True, True, True]
```

if you really want to store bools as their string representation your option would be to to use eval.

```
[eval(i) for i in items]
# [True, False, False, True, False]
```

or testing directly for equivalence using `i=='True'` as suggested in the first answer you got.

```
[(i == 'True') for i in items]
# [True, False, False, True, False]
```

---

but you can also ([and probably should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)) store them as their integer-string representation

```
some_string = "1, 0, 0, 1, 0"
items = some_string.split(', ')

print(items)
# ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0']

print([bool(int(i)) for i in items])
# [True, False, False, True, False]
```